# Intellij can't read images in resources subfolder

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

So I have a maven project in intellij and I want to load images from the resources folder.
It works perfectly for files that are directly in resources/. However, files that are in subfolder (for example resources/images/) are not found.

In this example, logo.png is correctly loaded while logo1.png is not found :

```
var img2 = new Image("logo1.png");
var img = new Image("images/logo.png");
```

I could put all my files directly in resources, but it would be all disorganized...

Here's the error I get when loading images/logo.png :

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1125)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:618)
    at org.example/org.example.App.start(App.java:25)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1117)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application org.example.App

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try `var img = new Image("/images/logo.png");` and `var img = new Image("/logo1.png");`

Comment: I tried. Still have the same error.

Comment: `getClass().getResource()` might be your friend if it somehow thinks you mean to read it as a file in the file system. Not sure how jfx `Image`s behave
Have to ask though: why is one image in `/images` but not the other?

Comment: `src/main/resources/images/logo.png` requires `new Image("/images/logo.png")`. All case sensitive. In modular java add the `images` package to your module-info.

Comment: new Image("/images/logo.png") does not work. I searched for getClass().getResource(), I think it might help me, however I don't know how to use it with JavaFX, using getClass().getResource() does not work inside new Image()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `var img2 = new Image("logo1.png");`

This code is just wrong, that's not how you load resources.

This is how you do it:

```
var img2 = new Image(TheClassThisCodeIsIn.class.getResource("logo1.png").toString());
```

The `new Image(string)` constructor takes as argument a **URL**, and `logo1.png` is not one of those.

In particular you are looking to load images from the exact same place java is loading your app's class files, which is done with `someClassInstanceThatIsUsedForContext.getResource`. The best context to use is no doubt the class you're in, hence, `TheClassYouAreIn.class`, which gets you that class instance. The `getResource` method returns a URL.

Note that the above construct is using **relative paths**: That code will look for a resource named `logo1.png` in the same place that `TheClassThisCodeIsIn.class` is located, even if it is in a jar file, dynamically created, or loaded over the network. In other words, if you have:

```
package com.foo.sashimisAwesomeApp;

public class MyApp {}
```

Then `MyApp.class.getResource("hello.png")` will look for `com/foo/sashimisAwesomeApp/hello.png`, because the class file for `MyApp` is at `com/foo/sashimisAwesomeApp/MyApp.class`. This means you need to match the package structure (That `com/foo/sashimisAwesomeApp` part) in your `resource` folder in your project directory structure. If you prefer to go from the 'root' of resources, include a leading slash: `MyApp.class.getResource("/images/icon.png")` will look in `/images/icon.png` in the jar file that also contains `/com/foo/sashimisAwesomeApp/MyApp.class`.

NB: Sidenote to the author of javafx's Image class: Geez, what a disaster. That API should obviously have taken in a URL or URI or have a static constructor to load off of classpath instead of this mess.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations ! I agree the API is not very intuitive

Comment: Please note the [`Image`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) documentation: "All URLs supported by URL can be passed to the constructor. If the passed string is not a valid URL, but a path instead, the Image is searched on the classpath in that case."  Note however, that, although you can have it implicitly search the classpath, I prefer this answer's suggestion of using `getResource` as it is more explicit to help understand how the image lookup is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

try using an absolute path "C:\

Comment: Specifically coding a Windows drive letter specifier such as `C:` is almost never a good way to resolve a resource lookup task.  It is not cross-platform and may not even work as expected on all Windows systems.